# What shape is this quadrilateral?

Tags: quadrilateral

It is a quadrilateral but I do not know which one it is:

[image: Image here]

Comment: It is a kite.  Kites can be concave or convex.

Comment: thanks @DougM !! But it isn't right for some reason

Comment: This can also be called a reflexed polygon.

Answer (score 2):

It is a type of **[kite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry))** (Also known as a **deltoid**). On the left hand side of the image below is a **convex** kite, and on the right hand side is a **concave** kite.

Image by [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Deltoid.svg):

[image]

A concave kite is sometimes referred as a **dart** or **arrowhead**.

Comment: Note that a deltoid is sometimes used to refer to a [Deltoid curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Deltoid.html), but it is also used to refer to a kite.